# userLocation.coordinate gave me wrong value

Tags: iphone, mapkit

when i try to get the current location using

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D CurrentLocation;
CurrentLocation = map.userLocation.coordinate;
```

i get the follwoing values:

```
CurrentLocation.latitude= -180.000000;
CurrentLocation.longitude= -180.000000;
```

and it is not my location at all.

do you know what is missing in this?

Comment: You have given your location as HIBA or the surroundings in Dameshq, keep your privacy. Be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that you have set the mapView's showUserLocation to TRUE.

Secondly, check that the value is not nil, as the mapView needs to locate the user first, and that takes a few seconds.

Comment: i load already put showUserLocation to TRUE.
which value i should check if it is nil?

Comment: `mapView.userLocation` or `mapView.userLocation.coordinate`

Comment: yes, map.userLocation.coordinate is -180.000000, map.userLocation.location.coordinate is 0.000000

knowing that the app show me my location perfectly.

Comment: Oh ok, you were meant to get the location.coordinate, fair enough.